# Tornadofx filterInput

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I'd like to make a special format for a text field to convert to doubles. However, I want to use a comma for decimal separation instead of periods. I've been researching for days and have looked at the guide but I'm still having trouble. `isDouble` doesn't seem to work when using commas. Even if I used periods, the data is formatted wrong when being written back (i.e. textfield 12.13 becomes 1213.00 in the database). This is what I have so far:

```
val format = DecimalFormat("##0.00", DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.GERMAN))

                        textfield(model.size, converter = object : StringConverter<Number>() {
                            override fun toString(number: Number?) = format.format(number)
                            override fun fromString(string: String?) = try {
                            format.parse(string).toDouble() } 
                            catch (e: ParseException) {0.0}
                        }){
                        filterInput {
                            val ba = mutableListOf<Boolean>().asObservable()
                            it.controlNewText.toCharArray().forEach { char ->
                                when {
                                    char.isDigit() -> ba.add(true)
                                    char == ',' -> ba.add(true)
                                    else -> ba.add(false)
                                }
                            }
                            when{
                                ba.any{false} -> return@filterInput false
                                else ->  return@filterInput true
                            } 
                        }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work? I know looping the old-school way and using variables (Gross!) isn't the coolest ways to handle things but the computation is relatively small and easy to understand.

```
filterInput {
                var decimalUsed = false
                loop@ for (char in it.controlNewText) {
                    if (char == ',') {
                        if (decimalUsed) {
                            return@filterInput false
                        } else {
                            decimalUsed = true
                        }
                    } else if (!char.isDigit()) {
                        return@filterInput false
                    }
                }
                true
            }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot yours is definetly still prettier than mine and it works thank you very much :)